# Undo a GIT push to the wrong shared repo

Tags: git, commit, undo

One of our developers accidentally pushed his local repo to the wrong shared repo.

I have managed to reset the header to the right location using git push and force, so that part is ok now.

However, I have not been able to get rid of the wrong commit, it shows up in gitk --all as a commit which has no parent and no children (that is it's not connected to any branch).

Is there a way to completely get rid of this one (we froze the shared repo so nobody has pulled since the last push)??

Answer (score 1):

The errornous commit is still in the git repository but is not refered to by any other commit (or branch) if I understand you correctly.

`git gc` will remove this commit as you already know by previous answers, however it will not delete objects that are newer than 2 weeks. (To prevent you from loosing data).

If you are really sure about what you're doing (have backups etc.) you can do `git gc --prune=<date>`. The help for `git gc`states:

"Prune loose objects older than date (default is 2 weeks ago, overridable by the config variable gc.pruneExpire). This option is on by default."

Answer (score 0):

You can run `git gc` in the remote repository. If the commit cannot be reach from any reference, it should be pruned from the repository. Be sure to make a backup before.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange state, I did such corrections many times and never saw those separate commits. 
Do you run gitk on the repo itself locally, or some clone?

I'd push up some empty/irrelevant commit and look again -- possibly the glitch just disappears. If not I'd run `git fsck`.

Also, if you clone the central repo, do you see the excess commit in the clone?